# How to pass data from multiple models to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 3 models

Student

```
public class Student
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; } //primary key


    [RegularExpression(@"^[ A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only Alphabet allowed")]
    [Required] //Because you can't leave this field empty
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[ A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only Alphabet allowed")]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{1,3})/\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Format has to be 1-3digit number/year; example 100/2015")]
    [Required]
    public string BI { get; set; }

}
```

Subject

```
public class Subject
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[ A-Za-z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only Alphabet and numbers allowed")]
    [Required]
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
}
```

Exam

```
public class Exam
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    public int SubjectID { get; set; }

    [Range(6, 10)]
    public int Grade { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Student Students;
    public IEnumerable<Exam> Exams;
    public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects;

}
```

I want to pass data from StudentsController to edit.cshtml, to be able to edit SubjectName and Grade from dropdown menu. I also created ViewModel from these 3, and included ViewModel. I just don't know how to pass ViewModel from controller to a view. Any ideas?

Controller edit

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var student = await _context.Student.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(student);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Name,LastName,BI,SubjectName,Grade")] ViewModel student)
    {
        if (id != student.Students.ID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(student);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!StudentExists(student.Students.ID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(student);
    }
```

Comment: how you action method looks like?

Comment: This is my Edit method from controller

Comment: Your code is quite confusing.  Do you need to Add grades for exams where the student and subject are already known?  I'm guessing you don't want to change the names of the subject, but select a different one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a `viewmodel` should just have properties that you are going to use on that `view` and not the entire `model`.

But you can pass a `ViewModel` like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var student = await _context.Student.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        model.Student = student;
        return View(model);
    }
```

And then on your `edit.cshtml` you need to `@model namespace.ViewModel`

Then on you `Post` method you should also use your `ViewModel` instead of a `Bind`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, ViewModel model)
{
   (...)
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `@model namespace.ViewModel`, or otherwise a combination of `@using namespace` with `@model ViewModel`

Comment: Yeah, i confused the language. Thank you. @PeterB

Comment: Yes, that can work. Just one more question. How can i make Dropdownlist out of that? Do i need a method in controller that will pass data, or should i use just in view Html.DropDownList?

Comment: I would make a `List` on my `controller` and send it to the `view` and then there you can access it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) is the documentation on how to do a dropdown list, just follow the steps, it's easy.

Comment: That is all i needed. I was missing List. Thank you!